# Why would ethernet not work after setting up dual boot?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, ethernet

So I have been setting up Ubuntu 14.04 on a separate ssd in my desktop for some machine learning development. I had been manually disconnecting my Win10 side or my Linux side whenever I was booting into the other, but I recently updated grub to be able to dual boot more conveniently.

After booting into windows and back into ubuntu, I started having ethernet connectivity problems to the point where ethernet is now not working at all and wifi is intermittent.

Here are some outputs:

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:bc:11:c6:54  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21f:bcff:fe11:c654/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:367 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:73157 (73.1 KB)  TX bytes:80690 (80.6 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1510 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1510 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:147748 (147.7 KB)  TX bytes:147748 (147.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:56:1d:d0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe56:1dd0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:81002 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:117394416 (117.3 MB)  TX bytes:4299198 (4.2 MB)
```

lspci | grep Ethernet:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2)     I218-V (rev 05)
```

NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:1F:BC:11:C6:54,

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

sudo ethtool eth0:

```
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

sudo /etc/dhclient:

```
sudo: /etc/dhclient: command not found
```

There seem to be a lot of these posts, and I've been through the first half dozen that come up on the Google. Also, the first time this happened, changing the NetworkManager.conf line from "managed=false" to "true" fixed it perfectly. After booting into windows and back into ubuntu, it seems to have gotten worse.

Oh, and I also get multiple "System Software Problem Detected" messages when I boot up now.

Thanks for any help!